# How to manipulate webRequest cookie in a cross-browser extension?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon

I am trying to edit `cookie` for all API calls using [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) from a cross-browser (supporting chrome and Firefox) extension which I am creating.

Following is the code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
 data => { /* cookie manipulation logic */ },
 { urls: ['https://*/*'] },
 ['blocking', 'requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders']
);
```

**Problem:** In Chrome, the code works with `extraHeaders` and in Firefox **the same code** works only if `extraHeaders` is removed. How can I make it work on both browsers?

Following is the browser doc reference for Chrome and Firefox.

**Chrome:**
Chrome documentation states that `extraHeaders` is needed if we want to manipulate cookie. Reference picture below. Reference link: [Link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/)

[image]

**Firefox:**

[Firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest#addlistener_syntax) doesn't tell to use any extra spec to manipulate cookie. Instead it gives error when `extraHeaders` is present in the third argument of addListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API exposes all predefined constants in chrome.webRequest.OnXXXXXXXXX objects for each event so only in new Chrome such objects will have `EXTRA_HEADERS` key with `extraHeaders` value whereas in Firefox and old Chrome it'll be undefined, which can be filtered out via `filter()`:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  listenerFunc,
  { urls: ['*://*/*'] },
  ['blocking', 'requestHeaders', 
   chrome.webRequest.OnBeforeSendHeadersOptions.EXTRA_HEADERS].filter(Boolean)
);
```